# Accessing angular $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What's the secret to accessing the angular.js `$http` object?

```
function MyController($scope) {
  $http... // not defined
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should inject it:

```
function MyController($scope, $http) {
   $http... // now is defined
}
```

More on [dependency injection docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

Comment: Huh, wish the docs on `$http` had told me it had to be injected... thanks.